# iPhone push notification sounds,'voice notification"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implement notifications in my IOS app, and I use customized sounds. Everything works fine.

But I'm not sure that this application will validate by apple if I use sounds with a voice that speaks.

For example, in one on my push notification, the sound is a voice that says:
"Presence detected"

**Someone has already published an application with "voice notification" and not "bipbip" or basic sounds?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple writes For sound:- (push notification)

"The name of a sound file in the application bundle. The sound in this file is played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The audio must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible with system sounds; see “Preparing Custom Alert Sounds” for details."

refers to:-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Comment: hi, I already read documentation, but I cant find informations about audio content, just the format and duration (30 seconds) file ...

Comment: You must use the afconvert tool to convert sounds. For example, to convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound Submarine.aiff to IMA4 audio in a CAF file

Comment: I have already applied the conversion and everything works fine, my only problem is whether Apple will accept my application with push notifications who use custom sounds with a voice that speaks.

Comment: sure ,apple is approve your app

Comment: check this http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/voice-recording-alarm-clock/id361691307?mt=8